# Dynamic height for UIViewController shown as modal popup

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, nslayoutconstraint, modalviewcontroller

I am currently trying to implement a custom `UIViewController` which has a `UINavigationController` inside. This is a modal view that will be visible on the bottom of the screen and the user has different options to navigate inside this modal view. The background of the `UIViewController` is set to clear, so it shows as an overlay of the already visible screen.

I have now managed to set up and present my `UIViewController` like this:

```
    let modalController = ModalController()
    modalController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.present(modalController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Inside this `UIViewController` I do this:

```
var popupController: UINavigationController = {
    let popupController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ModalStart())
    return popupController
}()

var modalPopup: UIView = {
    let modalPopup = UIView()
    modalPopup.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    modalPopup.backgroundColor = .white
    modalPopup.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return modalPopup
}()

view.addSubview(modalPopup)
modalPopup.addSubview(popupController.view)

modalPopup.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
modalPopup.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
modalPopup.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
modalPopup.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
```

This works fine but as you might guess already, the height is set to a fixed constant of 500. This works on my iPhone X, but would be different on iPhone 5s, for example. It also doesn't allow me to change the height accordingly when I navigate through the `UINavigationController`, as the height of the different `viewControllers` will be different.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this? I have already added a custom ContainerView inside my `rootViewController` (ModalStart), but I can't directly access popupController.containerView.frame.height (as popupController is a `UINavigationController`). I also tried to make the heightAnchor a variable and set it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` of ModalStart(), but this doesn't work either and fires constantly with different heights (if I print the height, it sometimes returns 480, sometimes 0, very strange behavior there).

I am wondering what the best approach for my specific case might be. Anything pointing my towards the right direction is very much appreciated!

Comment: Is modalpopup.topanchor working?

Comment: How do you mean? I can set modalPopup.topAnchor, yes. If I constraint this to the view's topAnchor with a constant of, let's say, 300, it shows perfectly fine. But this is not dynamic. I have tried to calculate the height of the containerView after viewDidLayoutSubviews() and change this accordingly with the height of the entire screen minus the height of the then calculated containerView. This initially works, but then I can't change the height as the height of popupController (with the UINavigationController inside) remains the same as the initial height.

Comment: why not setting the heightAnchor to a constant that depends on the screenSize. For example `modalPopup.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/yourConstant).isActive = true` That way you can get it to work dynamically depending on the screen size. You could also use the ViewController bounds if you don't want to use UIScreen size

Comment: That would not allow me to set the height according to the subviews. There are some subviews that can have a different height, for example a multiline UILabel. It would also be difficult to then change the height accordingly when the UINavigationController is pushed to another view, with another height.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are trying to get? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding it.

Comment: I edited my post. As you can see, I want to have a modal view on the bottom, with a NavController inside to make it possible to navigate back and forth. But I can’t seem to make the height dynamic.

Comment: How about set height ratio to superview.

Comment: Height ratio constraints.

Comment: @E.Coms How would I initiate that? If I want to relate it to the view of the NavigationController, it would return 0 as it is not layed out yet. If I want to set it in viewDidLayoutSubviews, I can't access it anymore.

Comment: If the height constrains is set as the view.heights let’ say 3/5, the autolayout will do it for you when needing layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna show you an easy way of doing it. From what I have seen, the best way to do it is to use a dataSource model for the modalView and calculate the height from there. For example, if you have an image and one label, which heights are known and if not can be calculated, you can send that as a dataSource for the modalView. Now, if the next modalView will only have 6 labels, again it will be easy to calculate the height that you need to have to fit them all. By using a dataSource model, you can then pre calculate all the height before the transition happens to the next modalView. I put together an easy example for you here: https://github.com/galots/VariableModal

If you click in the button that says Present, the new viewController will be presented and the modalView will be shown with an initial constraint. Then if you click Next, the modal view height will be updated accordingly to the dataSource. In this case the dataSource is just an array of `CGFloat`, just to make it easy to understand. Also, see that the modalView is a subclass of `UIView` so you can update its height constraint as needed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I however seem unable to find the relevant code and when I run in Xcode I can't see anything, just a white window. Can you link to the relevant code or file?

Comment: Sorry. Mistake while publishing. Here you go: https://github.com/galots/VariableModal

Comment: Whoa, that's amazing! Thank you so much for your example!